# Why email contents from web ui and python code are different from each other?

Tags: email, smtp, imap

I'm makeing a code that monitors an email account A and replys with the same subject and content.

For test, another email account B sends emails.

The email content is not only written in english, but also in other languages.

For English, everything goes well.(Both A and B get the same mails)

But when it comes to another language, the content that B gets shows in encoded(maybe) form, totally different from what B typed. (B typed = A got, B typed != B got)

But when I make a code that sends the same email(subject and content) from B to A, the content that B gets shows the exact content B typed. (B typed = A got = B got)

I guess something is applied while sending an email from web ui.
Does anyone know about this?

I cannot even decode the content, it doesn't show in MIME encoding format.(not "=?utf-8 blahblah ?=" foramt)

sample:

> "what B sent" -> "what my code got" -> "what B got for reply"
>
> For English,
>   subject: "subject" -> "subject" -> "subject"
>   content: "content" -> "content" -> "content"
>
> For Korean
>   subject: "제목" -> "=?UTF-8?B?7KCc66qp?=" -> "제목"
>   content: "내용" -> "64K07JqpDQo=" -> "64K07JqpDQo="

Thanks.

Comment: You can't even show us sample of what you got?

Comment: @Max I added a sample for better understanding.